# Ajuda chamar Rest e preencher outra table atráves de Click

Tags: javascript

Bom estou precisando de uma ajuda, tenho uma Datatable que já está funcionando dái quando eu clicar em um registro chamo um rest e pego os dados e tento popular a outra Datatable aí que está o problema já tentei de várias maneiras mas nunca exibe os dados, alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda? meu código abaixo como está hoje.

```
    $('#btnConsultar').click(function() {

        var apuracao = $('#indsApuracaos').val();
        var periodo = $('#txtPeriodo').val();
        var cpf = $('#txtCPF').val();
        var raizCNPJ = $('#empresaAgrupadora').val();

        tableEvtBasesTrab = $('#tableEvtBasesTrab').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "pageLength": 5,
            "searching":false,
            "destroy": true,
            "lengthMenu": [ [5], [5] ],
            "language": {
                "decimal":        "",
                "emptyTable":     "Sem dados dispon&#237;veis na tabela",
                "lengthMenu": "_MENU_ registros por p&#225;gina",
                "zeroRecords": "Nada Encontrado",
                "info": "P&#225;gina _PAGE_ / _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "Nenhum registro dispon&#237;vel",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totais)",
                "search": "Filtrar registros :",
                "loadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                "processing":     "Processamento...",
                "paginate": {
                    "first":      "Primeiro",
                    "last":       "&#218;ltimo",
                    "next":       "Pr&#243;ximo",
                    "previous":   "Anterior"
                },
                    "aria": {
                        "sortAscending":  ": Ativar para classificar coluna ascendente",
                        "sortDescending": ": Ativar para classificar coluna descendente"
                    }
                },
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "../rest/totalizadorS5001/busca",
                    parametros : [ 
                        {
                            name : 'apuracao',
                            value :  apuracao
                        },
                        {
                            name : 'periodo',
                            value :  $.utils.parseAnoMes($('#periodo').val())
                        },
                        {
                            name : 'cpf',
                            value :  cpf
                        },  
                        {
                            name : 'raizCNPJ',
                            value :  raizCNPJ
                        }
                    ],
                    "data": function ( data ) {
                    //
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                { 
                    "width": "20%",
                    "data": null,
                    "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        return data.atrIdEsoEve5001;
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "width": "20%",
                    "data": null,
                    "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        return data.atrNrRecArqBase;
                    } 
                },  
                { 
                    "width": "20%",
                    "data": null,
                    "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        return data.atrIndApuracao;
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "width": "20%",
                    "data": null,
                    "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        return data.atrPerApur;
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "width": "20%",
                    "data": null,
                    "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        return data.atrTpInsc;
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "width": "20%",
                    "data": null,
                    "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        return data.atrNrInsc;
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "width": "20%",
                    "data": null,
                    "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        return data.atrCpfTrab;
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "width": "20%",
                    "data": null,
                    "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        return data.atrId;
                    }
                }
                ],
                drawCallback : function( settings ) {
                //
                },
                "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
                "displayLength": 5
        });
    });

    $('#tableEvtBasesTrab tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        var esoEvento5001 = tableEvtBasesTrab.row(this).data();
        var atrIdEsoEve5001 = esoEvento5001.atrIdEsoEve5001;

        var dataSetProcJudTrab = new Array();

        $.rest.get({
            servico : 'totalizadorS5001/buscaPorId',
            parametros : [ 
                {
                    name : 'atrIdEsoEve5001',
                    value : atrIdEsoEve5001
                }
            ],
            sucesso : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                dataSetProcJudTrab = data.procJuds;
                console.log(dataSetProcJudTrab);
            }
        });

        var tableProcJudTrab = $('#tableProcJudTrab').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "pageLength": 5,
            "searching":false,
            "destroy": true,
            "data": dataSetProcJudTrab,
            "lengthMenu": [ [5], [5] ],
            "language": {
                "decimal":        "",
                "emptyTable":     "Sem dados dispon&#237;veis na tabela",
                "lengthMenu": "_MENU_ registros por p&#225;gina",
                "zeroRecords": "Nada Encontrado",
                "info": "P&#225;gina _PAGE_ / _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "Nenhum registro dispon&#237;vel",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totais)",
                "search": "Filtrar registros :",
                "loadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                "processing":     "Processamento...",
                "paginate": {
                    "first":      "Primeiro",
                    "last":       "&#218;ltimo",
                    "next":       "Pr&#243;ximo",
                    "previous":   "Anterior"
                },
                    "aria": {
                        "sortAscending":  ": Ativar para classificar coluna ascendente",
                        "sortDescending": ": Ativar para classificar coluna descendente"
                    }
                },
                "ajax": {
                    "data": function ( data ) {
                    //
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                { 
                    "width": "20%",
                    "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        console.log("Chegou Aqui");
                        console.log(data);
                        return data.atrNrProcJud;
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "width": "20%",
                    "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        return data.atrCodSusp;
                    } 
                }
                ],
                drawCallback : function(settings) {
                //
                },
                "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
                "displayLength": 5
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A ideia amigo como está hoje é somente popular quando eu clicar na linha do registro eu vou ter que popular mais umas 5 Datables diferentes ainda, por isso eu quero saber como faz em uma assim, pra mim resolver o resto, ele está fazendo uma chamada REST no código acima, que retorna um JSON já, queria saber do jeito que está como pegar o JSON e mostrar na Datatable. A tabela que eu quero preencher que está no código fonte é tableProcJudTrab.